# How to handle a communication buffer in C++?

Tags: c++

I have a communication buffer that is implemented in a Listner class as char commBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE]

What is the best way to create a communication buffer that is shared by all classes, instead of each class having this structure, pass it just a pointer to the buffer?

Comment: Do you have a *very* good reason for each listener *not* having their own read-buffer? And the obvious answer (synchronization issues not withstanding, which is **important**).. do the words `static` class member mean anything to you.?

Comment: The reason is space... each screen inherits the listner and that created 30K of Buffer space per screen

Comment: There can be a large number of these "screen" objects I take it?

Comment: Indeed there are over 30 screen objects that implement the Listner class.

Answer (score 0):

The *easiest* way is to declare `commBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];` global. I am not too sure of the `best` way. But if `best` in your case means `easiest` I would stick to global declaration. If you truly want to remain purely object oriented, put the `char commBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE]` into a `Singleton` class and read/write data to/from it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this and if it is threaded use a mutex to control access.

```
class Listener {
    static char commBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    static boost::mutex mutex;
};
```